# Nginx & UserDir & PHP

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I have a fairly simple nginx/1.4.7 installation (from Debian/unstable) and I'm trying to get PHP scripts to run inside a [UserDir](http://wiki.nginx.org/UserDir).

```
server {
        listen          8083;                                
        server_name     sid0.local;
        index           index.php index.html;
        root            /data/www/sid0.local;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # PHP-FPM
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include         fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
        }

        # UserDir
        location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
                alias           /home/$1/www$2;
                autoindex       on;
        }
}
```

Accessing `http://sid0.local/~dummy` works, it lists the content of `/home/dummy/www/` and I can access files there. Underneath `~dummy/bar` is a file called `index.php` - yet, accessing `http://sid0.local/~dummy/bar/` brings the dreaded "File not found." error (not a 404). The `error.log` has:

```
2014/04/30 23:07:44 [error] 4237#0: *9 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.103, server: sid0.local, request: "GET /~dummy/bar/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "sid0.local:8083"
```

Now, [many people](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Primary%20script%20unknown%22) seem to have this problem and some of them are even posting [solutions](https://gist.github.com/alanbriolat/1248004), like making sure that `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is set to `request_filename` - but this is already the case (it's set in fastcgi_params).

However, running `strace(1)` against the nginx process gives (edited for readability):

```
4045  connect(16, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"}, 110) = 0
4045  writev(16, [{"\1\1\0\1\0\10\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\4\0\1\3T\4\0\f\0
      QUERY_STRING\16\3
      REQUEST_METHODGET\f\0
      CONTENT_TYPE\16\0
      CONTENT_LENGTH\0170
      SCRIPT_FILENAME/data/www/sid0.local/~dummy/bar/index.php\v\25
      SCRIPT_NAME/~dummy/bar/index.php\v\f
      REQUEST_URI/~dummy/bar/\f\25
      DOCUMENT_URI/~dummy/bar/index.php\r\33
      DOCUMENT_ROOT/data/www/sid0.local
```

As you can see, `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is NOT `request_filename` but instead `document_root+fastcgi_script_name` - hence the 404, of course.

So, I guess my question is: why is my `SCRIPT_FILENAME` mangled (I even set it to `fastcgi_script_name`, no luck) and how do I get PHP scripts inside a `UserDir` running?

Comment: nginx `location`s are exclusive. If your request ends up in location for PHP files, nginx does not look for other matching locations therefore nginx does not know anything about `alias` directive in _userDir_ location.

Comment: Thanks. But when I've put the PHP part inside the UserDir part, it didn't change anything, `SCRIPT_FILENAME` was still mangled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change root dir rather than using alias in location. It could look like this:

```
listen          8083;                                
server_name     sid0.local;
index           index.php index.html;

# Here is magic
set $root_dir /data/www/sid0.local;
rewrite ^(/~[^/]+)$ $1/ redirect;
rewrite ^/~(?<user>[^/]+)(.+) $2;
if ($user) {
    set $root_dir /home/$user/www;
}
root $root_dir;

# PHP-FPM
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
}
```

Another version without rewrite:

```
listen          8083;                                
server_name     sid0.local;
index           index.php index.html;

root /data/www/sid0.local;

location ~ ^/~(?<user>[\w-]+)(?<path>/.*)$ {
    alias /home/lynn/tmp/site/$user/www$path;
    autoindex on;

    # PHP-FPM
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
    }
}
```

For some reason `alias` with named captures working, while with numeric references it fails. My guess, that numeric references are cleared somehow in nested location.

Comment: Wow, that's magic indeed. I'd have hoped that this could be done w/o rewrite tricks - it's only a userdir and rewrite rules (and [if](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)) always seem so fragile. Also, I cannot set `autoindex` inside the userdir anymore. But otherwise, this works, thanks!

Comment: @ckujau see update

Comment: Thanks for the update. Sorry, it took me a while to find time to test this. Unfortunately, this isn't working here, I'm getting 404 errors when trying to access ~dummy/bar/index.php. I shall take this to an nginx mailinglist. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Alexy Ten's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/748669/127467), I placed the following configuration files in `/etc/nginx/default.d/` as they are included by `nginx.conf` in my default install:

```
$ cat 00-index.conf 
index index.html;

$ cat 50-userdirs.conf
location ~ ^/~(?<user>[\w-]+)(?<path>/?.*)$ {
    alias /home/$user/www$path;
    autoindex on;
}
```

Notice the added `?` symbol after the `/` symbol to match `hostname/~user` without a trailing slash. That fixes one 404 error.

If you are getting 403 errors due to SELinux, you will need to update your access rules:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_user_content_t '/home/[^/]*/www/.*'
# for userdir in /home/* ; do restorecon -Rvi "$userdir/www" ; done
```